# Creating a mock terminal with a loop to delay CSS animations

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to create a website with a mock terminal that has the appearance of lines being typed, one after the other. I found a CSS animation that displays one character at a time, but I'm running into issues with delaying the animations of each line so that they aren't appearing all at once.

Here's my code:

```js
//attempted javascript loop 
// var code_lines =document.getElementsByClassName("line");

// for (i=0; i<=5; i++){
//   code_lines:nth-child(i).style.animation = "typing 2.5s steps(30, end)";
// }


//attemped jquery loop 
//$('#terminal_text').children('line').each(function () {
//    for (i=0; i<=5; i++){
//  i.style.animation = "typing 2.5s steps(30, end)";
//}
//});
```

```css
.terminal {
   width: 500px; 
  height: 500px;
  background-color: black; 
  color: white;
  padding: 20px;
}

.line {
   white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    animation: typing 2.5s steps(30, end);
}


/* The typing effect */
@keyframes typing {
  from { width: 0 }
  to { width: 100% }
}
```

```html
<div class="terminal"> 

<div id="terminal_text">
    <p class="line"> Last login:  </p>
    <p class="line">megan-byers:~ designelixir$ git clone https://github.com/coloradical/Rae_Portfolio.git </p>
    <p class="line">Cloning into 'Rae_Portfolio"...</p>
    <p class="line">remote: Loading website illustrations: 172 objects, done.</p>
    <p class="line">remote: Counting objects: 100% (172/172) done.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'll tweak timing, but for now I just want the animations to start one after another. I'm having a hard time finding clear examples of how to use class children to apply the animation. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Codepen: https://codepen.io/coloradical/pen/gOaMzjm

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60939523/8620333 .. maybe will give you a different idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I'd do it: first, remove the `line` class from your `<p>` tags and set them to `display:none`. Then, have a Javascript program add the `line` class to the first `<p>` and also add an event listener for the `animationend` event on that element. (Also change the CSS for `.line` so it has an additional rule for `display: block`.) When that event fires, it removes class `line` from the current `<p>` and adds the `line` class and the same event listener to the next `<p>`. (See [How do you detect when CSS animations start and end with JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14796936/how-do-you-detect-when-css-animations-start-and-end-with-javascript).)

In other words, every time `animationend` fires, it removes its triggering element's `line` class and adds the `line` class as well as an event listener to the next `<p>`.

https://codepen.io/km0ser/pen/xxwOjNb

```js
function do_it() {
  $("p.line")
    .removeClass("line")
    .addClass("done")
    .next()
    .addClass("line")
    .on("animationend", function () {
      do_it();
    });
}

$("#terminal_text p.line").on("animationend", function () {
  do_it();
});
```

```css
.terminal {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  padding: 20px;
}

.done {
  display: block !important;
}

#terminal_text p {
  display: none; /* hide by default */
}

.line {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  animation: typing 2.5s steps(30, end);
  display: block !important;
}

/* The typing effect */
@keyframes typing {
  from {
    width: 0;
  }
  to {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="terminal">

  <div id="terminal_text">
    <p class="line"> Last login: </p>
    <p>megan-byers:~ designelixir$ git clone https://github.com/coloradical/Rae_Portfolio.git </p>
    <p>Cloning into 'Rae_Portfolio"...</p>
    <p>remote: Loading website illustrations: 172 objects, done.</p>
    <p>remote: Counting objects: 100% (172/172) done.</p>

  </div>
</div>
```